# Why first element is destroyed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a piece of code like this:

```
class Data
{
    public:
        Data(const std::vector<int> &_data)
        {
            my_data = _data;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<int> my_data;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>> vec = {
        std::shared_ptr<Data>(new Data(std::vector<int>({ 1, 2 ,3 }))),
        std::shared_ptr<Data>(new Data(std::vector<int>({ 3, 4 ,5 })))
    };

    // breakpoint

    return 0;
}
```

somehow when I pause the program to check values (at breakpoint), the first (`vec[0]`) element is destroyed while the second one (`vec[1]`) is fine. What is going on here? Is that a bug in compiler? I am using new Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Did you drop a debug-out in a `Data::~Data()` destructor to confirm that? And are you possibly compiling with debug symbols on a release-build?

Comment: Yes, I added the `Data::~Data()` in order to check if object is getting destroyed and in both cases, Debug and Release, that is exactly what happened.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with the above code and the above setup. Both debug and release builds show the same behavior. Here's the output when I add trace `cout`s to the code: *1* **`Data::Data()`**, then *2* **`Data::Data()`**, then *3* **`Data::~Data()`**, then *4* **`BREAKPOINT`**, and finally *5* **`Data::~Data()`**.

Comment: how odd. I have to try this with vs2012 now.

Comment: @WhozCraig The initialization list syntax is not available in VC11, right? And I just checked it, even in VC12, when you use two `emplace_back` calls instead of constructing with the (outer) initialization list, the code behaves *correctly*.

Comment: I just tried using `std::make_shared` and it didn't help (the apparently erroneous behavior persists.)

Comment: @Qwrk In the `Data` constructor, if you change the signature to pass the parameter *by value* instead of by reference, the problem *disappears*. Note that passing by `const &` doesn't help. Also, if you change the internal member type of `Data` class to a simple `int`, instead of a `vector<int>`, the problem *goes away* (irrespective of how you pass it to the constructor.)

Comment: Then it's possibly a bug. Huge bug.

Comment: I reported this bug here: [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807610/first-element-of-vector-is-destroyed-initializing-from-initializer-list)

Comment: BTW, This code doesn't compile in VS2012.

Comment: I just tried VS2013 Update 1 and although the link to the bug reported above is listed as fixed the same problem occurs.

Comment: FYI, this code finally works correctly with VS2013 Update 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that a bug in VS2013 causes a double delete on the first item of the initializer_list.
Here's the flow:

1. initializer_list is constructed.
2. target vector is reserved a size of 1 and first item is copied (via copy constructor).
3. vector grows slowly to initializer_list size.
4. initializer_list is destroyed via a vector-destructor (i.e. `delete[]`). Last element is destroyed first.
5. First element is destroyed again via scalar-destructor (i.e. `delete`).

I've seen this on another post and verified the behavior using a debugger.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165166/double-delete-in-initializer-list-vs-2013/20168627#20168627)

For VS2013, initializer_list is good for basic types only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is something with the shared pointer note that a shared pointer object will be destroyed if
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed. 
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have VS2013, so I check the code in MinGW 4.7 in windows, I didn't found the problem above-mentioned. When I stop at that breakpoint, both the first (vec[0]) element and the second (vec[0]) element all is not destroyed.

So I guess that this problem's reason is that you write some simple code at that breakpoint, vs's complier optimize it, so you stopped at a strange place exactly between two elements' destructor function.

You can post out the disassembly code above that we can identify the problem explicitly. :)

Comment: I know it's not the problem in other compilers, that's why I reported this as a bug. Here is [disassembly code](http://ideone.com/MRlKjU) for main function, I think the 154 line is what causes this bug. :) And it doesn't matter if I put some extra code after declaration or not, it looks like it's getting destroyed right after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in compiler. If you add some logging to Data constructor and destructor then you will see that is going on.

```
std::cout << __FUNCTION << ":" << this << std::endl;
```

I confirm the issue in Visual Studio 2013. Under 'clang' this code behaves as expected.