# c++ initializer_list and shared_ptr behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

I'm testing vs2013 c++ initializer_list.

The code below can be compiled.
But crashes when i run exe.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

void DoSomething(std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Base> > list)
{
}

int main()
{
  auto ip = std::make_shared<Derived>();

  std::cout << "use_count=" << ip.use_count() << std::endl;

  DoSomething({ip, std::make_shared<Derived>()}); // ng
  // DoSomething({ip, std::make_shared<Base>()}); // ok
  // DoSomething({std::make_shared<Derived>(), ip}); // ok

  std::cout << "use_count=" << ip.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiles.

```
C:\...>cl.exe /EHsc test.cpp
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj

C:\...>
```

I expected the output like this.
g++4.8.2 works like this.

```
c:\...>test.exe
use_count=1
use_count=1
```

However, looks like this.

```
c:\...>test.exe
use_count=1
use_count=0 // or some random value like 3719232 and displayed crash dialog.
```

And, Modifying one line of the code above, This works good.

```
DoSomething({std::make_shared<Derived>(), ip});
```

Is this a bug or normal behavior of vs2013 initializer_list ?

Comment: This certainly seems like a bug.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19747981/420683 http://stackoverflow.com/q/20165166/420683

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bug or normal behavior of vs2013 initializer_list?

Yes to both. VS2013's `std::initializer_list` implementation is buggy; see similar questions  [Why first element is destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747981/420683) and [Double delete in initializer_list vs 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20165166/420683).

Someone reported one of those issues to Microsoft in November 2013: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807419/initializer-lists-leaking-memory

This is now fixed in the Spring Update:
[Bugs Fixed in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/09/bugs-fixed-in-the-spring-update.aspx)