# Swapping two list<string> leads to an access violation

Tags: c++, list, c++11, visual-studio-2013, swap

I am new to STL/C++11 programming, and am going through the motions to understand it.

And I am afraid I am stuck on what seems a trivial task, swapping string lists.

When I swap two lists of strings using the `std::swap()` method, I get no errors, but the list class member function, swap(), gives me an access violation:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<string> superheroes {"Spidey", "Supes", "Bats"};
    list<string> supervillains {"Goblin", "Luthor", "Joker"};
    std::swap(superheroes, supervillains);  //swaps fine
    superheroes.swap(supervillains); //access violation
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Pro 2013.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you post an SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: Your code is fine as shown here: http://ideone.com/UOrtmU  we'll need more details that the above to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Compiles fine on gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: Ok I edited it.  I am using visual studio pro 2013

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.  I have no idea what the problem is, but I started a new project with the same code, and was unable to reproduce the problem myself.  Corrupted file I guess.  But nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: *" I am using visual studio pro 2013"* <- this. There are bugs related to list initialization in VS2013. Try to use `push_back` instead of list-init. I'll see if I can find the bug reports.

Comment: See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807419/initializer-lists-leaking-memory and 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/20297191/420683 Please try without braced-init-lists, e.g. with `list<string> superheroes; superheroes.push_back("Spidey"); /* and so on */` and similarly for `supervillains`.

Comment: Will do dyp.  Much appreciated.  To think it's 2014, and MS hasn't ironed out 2011 c++ yet.  Lol.  Thanks.